# GKE Private cluster node status always unknown

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, gke-networking

I have provisioned a GKE private cluster using the below terraform script

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {    
  name     = var.cluster_name
  project  = var.project
  location = var.zone

  network    = google_compute_network.network.self_link
  subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.self_link

  logging_service    = "logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes"
  monitoring_service = "monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes"

  remove_default_node_pool = "true"
  initial_node_count       = 1

  addons_config {
    network_policy_config {
      disabled = false
    }
  }

  workload_identity_config {
    identity_namespace = format("%s.svc.id.goog", var.project)
  }

  master_auth {
    username = ""
    password = ""

    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = "false"
    }
  }

  network_policy {
    enabled = "true"
  }

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.secondary_ip_range.0.range_name
    services_secondary_range_name = google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.secondary_ip_range.1.range_name
  }

  master_authorized_networks_config {
    cidr_blocks {
      display_name = "bastion"
      cidr_block   = format("%s/32", google_compute_instance.bastion.network_interface.0.network_ip)
    }
  }
  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_endpoint = "true"
    enable_private_nodes    = "true"
    master_ipv4_cidr_block  = "172.16.0.16/28"
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "30m"
    update = "30m"
    delete = "30m"
  }

  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.service,
    google_project_iam_member.service-account,
    google_project_iam_member.service-account-custom,
    google_compute_router_nat.nat,
  ]

}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "private-np-1" {
  name       = "private-np-1"
  location   = var.zone
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.cluster.name
  node_count = "3"

  management {
    auto_repair  = "true"
    auto_upgrade = "false"
  }

  node_config {
    machine_type = "e2-micro"
    disk_type    = "pd-standard"
    disk_size_gb = 100
    image_type   = "COS"

    service_account = google_service_account.gke-sa.email
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append",
    ]

    labels = {
      cluster = var.cluster_name
    }

    workload_metadata_config {
      node_metadata = "GKE_METADATA_SERVER"
    }

    metadata = {
      google-compute-enable-virtio-rng = "true"
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }
  }

  depends_on = [
    google_container_cluster.cluster,
  ]
}
```

Here's my network terraform script:

```
resource "google_service_account" "gke-sa" {
  account_id   = format("%s-node-sa", var.cluster_name)
  display_name = "GKE Security Service Account"
  project      = var.project
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "service-account" {
  count   = length(var.service_account_iam_roles)
  project = var.project
  role    = element(var.service_account_iam_roles, count.index)
  member  = format("serviceAccount:%s", google_service_account.gke-sa.email)
}


resource "google_project_service" "service" {
  count   = length(var.project_services)
  project = var.project
  service = element(var.project_services, count.index)

  disable_on_destroy = false
}

resource "google_compute_network" "network" {
  name                    = format("%s-network", var.cluster_name)
  project                 = var.project
  auto_create_subnetworks = false

  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.service,
  ]
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetwork" {
  name          = format("%s-subnet", var.cluster_name)
  project       = var.project
  network       = google_compute_network.network.self_link
  region        = var.region
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/24"

  private_ip_google_access = true

  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = format("%s-pod-range", var.cluster_name)
    ip_cidr_range = "10.1.0.0/16"
  }

  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = format("%s-svc-range", var.cluster_name)
    ip_cidr_range = "10.2.0.0/20"
  }
}
resource "google_compute_address" "nat" {
  name    = format("%s-nat-ip", var.cluster_name)
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region

  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.service,
  ]
}

resource "google_compute_router" "router" {
  name    = format("%s-cloud-router", var.cluster_name)
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  network = google_compute_network.network.self_link

  bgp {
    asn = 64514
  }
}

resource "google_compute_router_nat" "nat" {
  name    = format("%s-cloud-nat", var.cluster_name)
  project = var.project
  router  = google_compute_router.router.name
  region  = var.region

  nat_ip_allocate_option = "MANUAL_ONLY"

  nat_ips = [google_compute_address.nat.self_link]

  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS"

  subnetwork {
    name                    = google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.self_link
    source_ip_ranges_to_nat = ["PRIMARY_IP_RANGE", "LIST_OF_SECONDARY_IP_RANGES"]

    secondary_ip_range_names = [
      google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.secondary_ip_range.0.range_name,
      google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.secondary_ip_range.1.range_name,
    ]
  }
}



locals {
  hostname = format("%s-bastion", var.cluster_name)
}

resource "google_service_account" "bastion" {
  account_id   = format("%s-bastion-sa", var.cluster_name)
  display_name = "GKE Bastion SA"
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "bastion-ssh" {
  name          = format("%s-bastion-ssh", var.cluster_name)
  network       = google_compute_network.network.name
  direction     = "INGRESS"
  project       = var.project
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["22"]
  }

  target_tags = ["bastion"]
}

data "template_file" "startup_script" {
  template = <<-EOF
  sudo apt-get update -y
  sudo apt-get install -y tinyproxy
  EOF

}

resource "google_compute_instance" "bastion" {
  name = local.hostname
  machine_type = "g1-small"
  zone = var.zone
  project = var.project
  tags = ["bastion"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  metadata_startup_script = data.template_file.startup_script.rendered

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.name

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }

  allow_stopping_for_update = true

  service_account {
    email = google_service_account.bastion.email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }

  // This provider is used to block the subsequent providers until the instance
  // is available.
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
        READY=""
        for i in $(seq 1 20); do
          if gcloud compute ssh ${local.hostname} --project ${var.project} --zone ${var.region}-a --command uptime; then
            READY="yes"
            break;
          fi
          echo "Waiting for ${local.hostname} to initialize..."
          sleep 10;
        done
        if [[ -z $READY ]]; then
          echo "${local.hostname} failed to start in time."
          echo "Please verify that the instance starts and then re-run `terraform apply`"
          exit 1
        fi
EOF
  }
}
```

In summary what the above script is doing are:

1. Creating a VPC with Subnet (2 secondary IP ranges)
2. Create NAT for all egress
3. Create a GKE cluster within the VPC (with only private endpoints) with 3 nodes.
4. Create a Bastion GCE with ingress allowed from internet over tcp:22 (through firewall) for tunneling to private master endpoint.

These resources are all getting creating fine, however the node statuses are very unstable. Only one of the nodes is switching statuses (frequently) between ready and unknown. The rest 2 nodes are always in status unknown. Any deployment (even ingress controller deployment) is failing.

I am not an expert with GKE.

What is the issue here? Why nodes are in "unknown status"?

Comment: Would you please select 'e2-medium' [default](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#machine_type) machine type to create GKE cluster?

Comment: I can try that. Are you suggesting that e2-micro are too small to host kubelet and its internal pods? (I had created public cluster before with micro and they are still running fine because the deployments on it are small micro services).

Comment: As I'm able to create GKE cluster using 'e2-micro' on the test project via GUI. I would like to suggest you to also try to create cluster from GUI. If you are able to provision a cluster then the issue might be with the terraform script.

Comment: You can also check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271574/11866104

Answer (score 0):

If the node is marked in Unknown state, it means it cannot communicate with the control plane API Server.

Additionally, There might be user installed webhooks which might interfere with kube-system pods. These webhooks might prevent CNI plugins from starting and make a node NotReady/unknown.

Sometimes this issue occurs because of overloaded resources, the node might end up in an unhealthy state if there aren't sufficient resources for it to function.

If the issue occurs next time, the command 'kubectl describe node ' would greatly assist in resolving the situation.

Typically, the node enters an unknown status due to any of the conditions listed below.
OutOfDisk
MemoryPressure
DiskPressure